# Asp.net MVC AuthorizationFilter and AjaxRequests

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, action-filter

I have an authorization filter class:

```
public class ValidateSessionTokenFilter : IAuthorizationFilter
{
    public void OnAuthorization(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        if (filterContext.HttpContext.Request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            filterContext.Result = new JsonResult
            {
                Data = new { Message = "Session timeout" },
                JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet
            };
            filterContext.HttpContext.Response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
        }
    }
}
```

The filter works, but the problem is that even if i force the return type to be a `JsonResult` result, the framework always returns a redirect to login page.

Is there any way of preventing this behavior?

Comment: is there some code after if block

Comment: It is, but is not important for the example

Comment: but might help for better understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's the default behaviour of Forms Authentication when you return a 401. Afaik there's no 
setting to disable that behavior in .Net < 4.5 so, the workaround besides using your own auth system, is something like this:
- return a custom code (something like 4100)
- hook up on the EndRequest event then check it out

```
if (context.Response.StatusCode==4100)
 {
       context.Response.StatusCode=401;
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a MVC issue with HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized, it always do redirect. We "fix" this issue with returning custom error code.

p.s. If you really need this I can find code witch is responsible for this.

Comment: I need the status code 401 to handle it properly from client side.  But, i found a fix: i need to suppress forms authentication redirect. `filterContext.HttpContext.Response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;`

Comment: You can call `HttpContext.Response.End();` after setting the status code 401 in your Action. Working for MVC 5.2.2.0